# Escape js strings in order not to be evaluated as javascript

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I do not know how it's called the process to block the evaluation of js strings to js code (something like js injection[from sql injection] i have no clue so please tell me in case you know). But I need to be able to achieve that, can you give me an advice?

String example:

```
"name": " /><img src=\"\" onerror=\"javascript:alert('random sad@#! string]')\" />",
```

For instance I read this from a json which will be set as the title of a dom element, when rendered, this will throw a alert popup.

Thank you

Comment: FYI this class of vulnerability is called [XSS/Cross Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Don't do that. If you can create elements with JS and add attributes programmatically.

Comment: @MarcoL I dont get it, if i build tree froma json response, what is it wrong with it?

Comment: The main problem comes when you're injecting a tag to the DOM from an unescaped string. Building the DOM node with JS methods makes the injection way harder.

Comment: I do that...., i am not simply storing html >.<